# Does spring-data-jpa has a L2 cache implementation?

Tags: java, caching, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create Repository with L2 cache with minimal setting. My database is postgresql.

I start with spring-boot-sample-data-jpa-archetype project using maven.
I have removed the HSQL and create a DataSource bean to connect to postgresql.
Also use ddl to create schema and imported the initial script data.

I have also added the @Cacheable to my entities.
Then I use unit test to query an entity 10 times using repository. It took 1~49ms. So that leaves me two questions.

1. Does repository benefits from L1 cache? how do I know if I am hitting the cache or data source?
2. How to enable L2 cache? does Spring data has its own implementation?

Comment: Spring Data JPA is just a wrapper around JPA. If you want to use an L2 cache, it totally depends on the used JPA implementation (which by default in Spring Boot would be Hibernate).

Comment: @dunni does Java 8 has a bundle JPA implementation?

Comment: No. JPA is not part of the JDK

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some testing and the help from @dunni, I will answer my own question.
Spring uses Hibernate as an implementation of JPA. Spring data provides some wrapper over Hibernate. Also need to choose a caching implementation.

To enable L2 cache, add these properties to your project.

1. spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
2. spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
3. spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory

also add these dependencies:
hibernate-ehcache

Then, add @Cacheable(true) to your entity model class.
Extends a repository interface, Spring will generate the implementation using naming convention. For example

```
@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.cacheable", value="true")})
Entity findByName(String name)
```

You can also implement the interface. But that will require adding a hint to your query object to activate L2 cache.

```
query.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true);
```

To verify the cache is working, you can use the following properties to see if the SQL has been executed.

1. spring.jpa.show-sql=true
2. spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

Answer (score 0):

after reading your comment and checking my code, my code started working. Also, with adding `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true`
i can see my db calls more detailed. [demo project link](https://github.com/Kambaa/spring-boot-3-examples/tree/hibernate-2nd-level-cache)

[image: Log of calling same endpoint twice]

Thank you